# How can I make QueryDSL joining query?

Tags: java, querydsl

I'm new in QueryDSL and having trouble creating a QueryDSL query with joins. My code is as under:

```
class LeadDetail {
  private User user;
  ...
}

class User {
  private Site site;
  ...
}

class Site {
  private Company company;
  ...
}
```

When I try to create a QueryDSL query with the clause `QLeadDetail.leadDetail.user.site.company.id.eq(companyId);` I'm able to get the path till `user.site`, but the path `company` is `null`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Timo Westkämper Plz answer me ASAP.

Comment: QueryDSL [initializes only direct references](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.2.3/reference/html/ch03s02.html) on Q-classes. Deeper paths can be initialized using the `@QueryInit` annotation. `class LeadDetail { @QueryInit("*.*") private User user; }` and `class User { @QueryInit("*.*") private Site site; }` should do the trick.

Comment: This is not working dear... Another solution???

Comment: Works fine for me. See [my sample](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/41384856) based on your code. Take a look at the [Lead class](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/blob/master/41384856/src/main/java/org/example/domain/Lead.java) and the [LeadRepository interface](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/blob/master/41384856/src/main/java/org/example/data/LeadRepository.java). You can run tests as `mvn test` to verify that everything works fine.